# (ruby) If a conditional variable is nil in an if-else block statement, what will the program print in ruby?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, let's suppose we have this code:

```
foo = nil
if foo
  puts "foo is true"
else
  puts "foo is false"
end
```

what will this above program print exactly?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @JörgWMittag please see my answer below ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134199/16033809)) and other's answers too.

Comment: @aashish, I don't think Jörg needs help here.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, Ruby developers do not care that much if a variable or condition is exactly `true` or `false`. Instead Ruby has the concept of *truthy* and *falsey* values.

`false` and `nil` are *falsey*, everything else is *truthy*.

In your example

```
if foo
  puts "foo is true"
else
  puts "foo is false"
end
```

the output would be "foo is false" because `nil` is *falsey* and therefore the `else` block is evaluated.

When running the example in the console then `nil` would be returned at the end, because `nil` is returned by the `puts` method (see [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/IO.html#method-i-puts)) and the Ruby console always returns the return value of the last method call.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that code above will print "foo is false" and also output nil. If someone knows why please comment on this answer or post a new answer to the above question.

So,

```
if foo
  puts "foo is true"
else
  puts "foo is false"
end
```

will print:
foo is false 
=> nil
if you are using ruby console

Update: The user "spickermann" explained it perfectly here I think, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134502/16033809)